# How To Make Authorization JSON API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Hey guys I have been pulling my hair out thinking about this JSON API authorization. I had successfully make an API for reviews but when I'm calling out reviews endpoint [using token], it shows all reviews in database, **what I wanna do is showing reviews associated with current user. How can I achieve this?**. Thank you in advance.

this is my reviews controller code :

```
module Api
    module V1
        class ReviewsController < Api::ApiController
            respond_to :json
            before_action :authenticate 

            def index
                respond_with Review.all
            end

            def show
                respond_with Review.find(params[:id])
            end

            def create
                respond_with Review.create(params[:product])
            end

            def update
                respond_with Review.update(params[:id], params[:products])
            end

            def destroy
                respond_with Review.destroy(params[:id])
            end

            private

              def authenticate
              authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
              User.find_by(access_token: token)
              end

           end

        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
User.find_by(access_token: token)
```

do

```
@user = User.find_by(access_token: token)
```

Then in your index action...

```
respond_with @user.reviews
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, but I have little bit problem when changes this code as your suggestion. the problem is when I visiting my reviews API endpoint in chrome it keeps giving me **HTTP Token: Access denied** error but it worked perfectly when I tried to CURL in terminal :

**curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/reviews -H 'Authorization: Token token="8f8315d4892044479450ef3403c0af95"'**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying you DIDN'T have this problem before my change?

Comment: No, I had this problem before but I didn't notice.

Comment: Ok, but that's a new problem, so should be a new SO question. Can you post it as a new question?

Comment: Ok I will post a new question,